# Why I obtain this Spring Exception No qualifying bean of type is defined expected single matching bean but found 2?

Tags: java, spring

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have the following doubt:

When I perform a JUnit test method I obtain this error message (it is expected by the user guide provided and then explain how fix it):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [rewards.internal.account.AccountRepository] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: stubAccountRepository,jdbcAccountRepository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:970)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:811)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:739)
    ... 43 more
```

From what I understand it happens because Spring found multiple bean of the same type: **stubAccountRepository** and **jdbcAccountRepository**:

This is the **StubAccountRepository** class:

```
/**
 * A dummy account repository implementation. Has a single Account
 * "Keith and Keri Donald" with two beneficiaries "Annabelle" (50% allocation)
 * and "Corgan" (50% allocation) associated with credit card "1234123412341234".
 * 
 * Stubs facilitate unit testing. An object needing an AccountRepository can
 * work with this stub and not have to bring in expensive and/or complex
 * dependencies such as a Database. Simple unit tests can then verify object
 * behavior by considering the state of this stub.
 */
@Repository
public class StubAccountRepository implements AccountRepository {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StubAccountRepository.class);

    private Map<String, Account> accountsByCreditCard = new HashMap<String, Account>();

    /**
     * Creates a single test account with two beneficiaries. Also logs creation
     * so we know which repository we are using.
     */
    public StubAccountRepository() {
        logger.info("Creating " + getClass().getSimpleName());
        Account account = new Account("123456789", "Keith and Keri Donald");
        account.addBeneficiary("Annabelle", Percentage.valueOf("50%"));
        account.addBeneficiary("Corgan", Percentage.valueOf("50%"));
        accountsByCreditCard.put("1234123412341234", account);
    }

    public Account findByCreditCard(String creditCardNumber) {
        Account account = accountsByCreditCard.get(creditCardNumber);
        if (account == null) {
            throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException(1);
        }
        return account;
    }

    public void updateBeneficiaries(Account account) {
        // nothing to do, everything is in memory
    }
}
```

And this is the **JdbcAccountRepository **:

/**
 * Loads accounts from a data source using the JDBC API.
 */ 
@Repository
public class JdbcAccountRepository implements AccountRepository {

```
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JdbcAccountRepository.class);

private DataSource dataSource;

/**
 * Constructor logs creation so we know which repository we are using.
 */
public JdbcAccountRepository() {
    logger.info("Creating " + getClass().getSimpleName());
}

/**
 * Sets the data source this repository will use to load accounts.
 * @param dataSource the data source
 */
@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public Account findByCreditCard(String creditCardNumber) {
    String sql = "select a.ID as ID, a.NUMBER as ACCOUNT_NUMBER, a.NAME as ACCOUNT_NAME, c.NUMBER as CREDIT_CARD_NUMBER, b.NAME as BENEFICIARY_NAME, b.ALLOCATION_PERCENTAGE as BENEFICIARY_ALLOCATION_PERCENTAGE, b.SAVINGS as BENEFICIARY_SAVINGS from T_ACCOUNT a, T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY b, T_ACCOUNT_CREDIT_CARD c where ID = b.ACCOUNT_ID and ID = c.ACCOUNT_ID and c.NUMBER = ?";
    Account account = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, creditCardNumber);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        account = mapAccount(rs);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SQL exception occurred finding by credit card number", e);
    } finally {
        if (rs != null) {
            try {
                // Close to prevent database cursor exhaustion
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                // Close to prevent database cursor exhaustion
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                // Close to prevent database connection exhaustion
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
    return account;
}

public void updateBeneficiaries(Account account) {
    String sql = "update T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY SET SAVINGS = ? where ACCOUNT_ID = ? and NAME = ?";
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        for (Beneficiary beneficiary : account.getBeneficiaries()) {
            ps.setBigDecimal(1, beneficiary.getSavings().asBigDecimal());
            ps.setLong(2, account.getEntityId());
            ps.setString(3, beneficiary.getName());
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SQL exception occurred updating beneficiary savings", e);
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            try {
                // Close to prevent database cursor exhaustion
                ps.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                // Close to prevent database connection exhaustion
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Map the rows returned from the join of T_ACCOUNT and T_ACCOUNT_BENEFICIARY to an fully-reconstituted Account
 * aggregate.
 * @param rs the set of rows returned from the query
 * @return the mapped Account aggregate
 * @throws SQLException an exception occurred extracting data from the result set
 */
private Account mapAccount(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    Account account = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (account == null) {
            String number = rs.getString("ACCOUNT_NUMBER");
            String name = rs.getString("ACCOUNT_NAME");
            account = new Account(number, name);
            // set internal entity identifier (primary key)
            account.setEntityId(rs.getLong("ID"));
        }
        account.restoreBeneficiary(mapBeneficiary(rs));
    }
    if (account == null) {
        // no rows returned - throw an empty result exception
        throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException(1);
    }
    return account;
}

/**
 * Maps the beneficiary columns in a single row to an AllocatedBeneficiary object.
 * @param rs the result set with its cursor positioned at the current row
 * @return an allocated beneficiary
 * @throws SQLException an exception occurred extracting data from the result set
 */
private Beneficiary mapBeneficiary(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    String name = rs.getString("BENEFICIARY_NAME");
    MonetaryAmount savings = MonetaryAmount.valueOf(rs.getString("BENEFICIARY_SAVINGS"));
    Percentage allocationPercentage = Percentage.valueOf(rs.getString("BENEFICIARY_ALLOCATION_PERCENTAGE"));
    return new Beneficiary(name, allocationPercentage, savings);
}
```

}

From what exactly depend the previous error message?

I think that this is a configuration problem that happens at the application startup. Is it correct?

And I think that this due to the fact that both the classes are annoted with **@Repository** (**StubAccountRepository** and **JdbcAccountRepository**) and implements the **AccountRepository** interface so Spring could not know what class use as implemented repository for **AccountRepository**.

Is my reasoning correct or am I missing something? Can you give me more explaination about this situation?

Tnx

Comment: Yep, correct, you should specify bean name and use Qualifaer annotation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well Maksym has already told you, but to make it more clear for you I'll try to be more detailed.

You have 2 implementations of 'AccountRepository' interface: StubAccountRepository and JdbcAccountRepository. When you use @Autowired annotation on type 'AccountRepository' then you just tell Spring to perform 'autowire by type'. And so Spring checks type of the field that should be autowired and tries to locate a SINGLE bean of that type (as if you called ApplicationContext.getBean(AccountRepository.class)). Since it fails to locate a SINGLE bean of that type, the ApplicationContext fails to start.